# Azure DevOps XmlTransformation not working properly

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I created a release pipeline it is working very well but the XML transformation part is not working as I wanted.

I gave a name for my stage as "Development" and I have "Web.Development.config" file as I showed below, I checked the "XML transformation option" but not is changed. When I add "Web.Release.config" it works but I want to use "Web.Development.config" for the Development environment, I want to use "Web.Production.config" for the Production environment.

When I removed the "Web.Release.config" nothing happens.

When I added the "Web.Release.config" nothing happens. It is skipping or not using "Web.Development.config".

What am I missing? What is the wrong part?

[image: Web config files]

[image: Release Pipeline Definition Preview]

[image: Release Stage Preview]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying a lot of things, finally, I found a solution to my problem. These are the steps:

1. Go to your build definition, choose "Build Solution" task and add "/p:autoparameterizationwebconfigconnectionstrings=false" as an argument. If you don't do that, the xml transformation process will skip replacing "connectionString" attribute.

[image]

2. Make your all config files as content and mark them as copy always. After your edit, they should be like below in your project file. You should remove Web.config tag.

[image]

3. Go to your release definition and check the XML transformation option.
4. Make sure that you gave the same name to your stage with your *..config file.
   You can check this link for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 0):

By default Azure DevOps uses your `web.config` and `web.release.config` and then applies an environment specific config. There is no way to exclude `web.release.config` from your transformations except from renaming/deleting the file.

See the docs on [XML Transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops#xml-transformation) for all the details.

Comment: but in the image he doesn't have `web.release.config`

Comment: @wouter de Kort, thanks for your reply. I added again as you said, web.release.config but this time it is not applying my settings. It is applying only release settings.